# Bootstrap make full width full height column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following layout:

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      ...
  </nav>

  <div class="jumbotron">
     ...
  </div>

  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">...</div>
     </div>

     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Navbar and header take up 100% of the screen width. However, the columns don't - huge empty margins remain near the left and right edges of the screen.

If I remove the `container` div everything takes up 100% of the space and it works fine by me, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice since in alll examples `container` is used. Also, I want to make the columns take up all the space to the end of the page and not sure if `container` is necessary to accomplish it.

Comment: use container-fluid

Answer (score 1):

Per the Bootstrap documentation, a container is required. You can use `container-fluid` instead of `container` if you want full-width containers. You can find this in the Bootstrap 3 documentation here:

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

You can find info about this in the Bootstrap 4 documentation here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/